# How to get gzip compressed response of static files which is loaded in HTML script tag

Tags: google-app-engine, browser, gzip

I'm developing web application on App Engine(nodejs10 as runtime, Node as server, and React as frontend).

For better performance indicated by Lighthouse, I am trying to make every response compressed in gzip.
Currently gzip compression worked for API response, but does not for script tag.

In server.js, I've introduced compression module, and that worked. Every internal api call response is gzipped.

```
import compression from 'compression';

.
.

app.use(
  compression({
    threshold: 1,
    level: 9,
    memLevel: 1,
  }),
);

.
.
```

Gzip file is locally generated and located in same place as raw Javascript files.
Here's in webpack.config.js.

```
new CompressionPlugin({
  test: /\.(css)|(js)$/,
  compressionOptions: {
    level: 9,
  },
}),
```

In html, I'm trying to load frontend files.
I suppose App Engine handles the rest if content can be encoded or not according to `accepting-encoding` and `user-agent`.

Here's the problem. Every static files remain unzipped.

```html
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/client.js" charSet="utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/vendors.chunk.js" charSet="utf-8" />
</body>
```

Request headers

```
:authority: myApplicaation
:method: GET
:path: /assets/client.js
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: ja,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
cache-control: no-cache
cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1338918906.1558605919; __stripe_mid=1091f2c2-d01d-4386-871b-ee420a840bd5; _gcl_au=1.1.2059850586.1566453250; _gid=GA1.2.969451871.1566667214; connect.sid=s%3AIINmpsd-30ad8TF5z7oCBDo4h1jIxgRQ.XxT3L7%2F8H2tVcS4COIrpy7SxCp746FnIKNjthLW1P8Q; __stripe_sid=edda0dd4-1fbf-4da9-bcdc-9dccab9bdf4e; _gat_UA-125249076-1=1
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://tripper.world/
sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15A372 Safari/604.1
```

Response headers

```
accept-ranges: bytes
age: 371502
cache-control: public, max-age=5184000
content-length: 1417405
content-type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
date: Sat, 24 Aug 2019 03:47:28 GMT
etag: W/"15a0bd-16cb7e22578"
last-modified: Thu, 22 Aug 2019 05:52:27 GMT
server: Google Frontend
status: 200
x-cloud-trace-context: 6304083a50ed3fa42285e3e229af07a8
x-powered-by: Express
```

Is there any way to make static files gzipped?
If my any assumption are wrong, please point them out.

I appreciate your helps in advance, Thanks.

**********Additional information**********

static file's served via express static.

```
app.use(
  express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'), {
    maxAge: '60d',
  }),
);
```

app.standard.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs10
instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.65
  min_instances: 0
  max_instances: 1
beta_settings:
 cloud_sql_instances: 'xxxxxx-xxxxxx:asia-northeast1:xxxxxx-postgres'
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

Comment: whats your `app.yaml` look like

Comment: Are your static files served by Express, or by App Engine by using static_files in your app.yaml configuration?

Comment: @ryanm Thanks for you help. I added them above.  Is using App Engine better for static files?

Comment: @Alex Thanks for your comment. Please find above app.standard.yaml!

Answer (score 1):

Try in your Express application something like (I haven't tested):

```
const path = require('path')

const setStaticHeaders = (res, assetPath) => {
  const assetExtension = path.extname(assetPath);
  // Only apply to assets Webpack compressed
  if (['.js', '.css'].includes(assetExtension)) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
  }
}
app.use(
  express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'), {
    maxAge: '60d',
    setHeaders: setStaticHeaders
  }),
);
```

Webpack is GZipping your assets but not setting the correct response header. You also only want to apply that header for the actual assets that Webpack Gzipped, in case there are other non-compressed assets in your assets folder (which there might not be).

It looks like App Engine will automatically [GZip static assets for you](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/). So you could also remove the GZip in the Webpack config and just [serve the files using App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/serving-static-files).

Answer (score 0):

Try serving your static assets via GAE's `static_dir` handler in `app.yaml`

```
handlers:
- url: /assets
  static_dir: path/to/assets/folder
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

and google should automatically gzip it based on the request headers it receives

Comment: Thanks so much that way worked. Is there any docs that specify about it ? Is Express way prioritized if I serve both App Engine and Express ?

Comment: it's alluded to a few times (go here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/ and search "gzip") but it doesnt seem to be directly documented. and i'm not sure what you mean by "prioritized". When you make a request to GAE, it checks the `handlers` section of your `app.yaml` and picks the first one in the list that matches. `- url: /.* script: auto` is the one that hits your express code